# Is there a direct way to get ruby's gem path from rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I would like to get the path of the gem directory for the current ruby (under rbenv).

This gives me the bin dir:

```
rbenv which ruby
```

which I could chop around and suite my needs, but I'd like to see if there is something more direct.

I'm thinking that

```
rbenv prefix
```

is the best choice.  This leaves me with something like

```
/Users/newalexandria/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448
```

to which I append

```
/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
```

I'm worried about the gems version. 
Would like to see anything better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there seems now to be a current command that provides support for the feature.

```
$ gem env home
/Users/newalexandria/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: this seems to be a modern / current command that provides support for the feature.  Great.

Comment: So, it turns out this feature has existed [since 2008](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/c746244579df96e090b2a276533a2b28bf1b19d4). Documentation was added at some later point (perhaps as recently as June 2022).

Answer (score 4):

`rbenv exec gem environment` returns information about your rubygems install.

Use it with grep to isolate the directory:

```
$ rbenv exec gem environment | grep INSTALLATION
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: $HOME/.rbenv/versions/X.X.X-pX/lib/ruby/gems/X.X.X
```

Comment: It's now 2021 and I got a stray thumbsdown; I'm not inclined to check the current validity of this answer, but anyone who finds this is now incorrect is welcome to explain how/why it's incorrect. And to anyone looking for the real answer, buyer beware!

Comment: seems there are cleaner answers now.  I think your answer should remain, and not-downvoted, because it teaches another informative way to get this information